# how to match regex route in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

i'm trying to make this code snippet from the sinatra tutorial work so that I can set some routes based on regex matching.  it doesn't seem to be working and I'm copy pasting direct from the tutorial, any ideas on what i'm missing.  make the assumption that my sinatra app is working and i have other correctly structured GET routes working so I'm unclear why a direct copy past like this doesn't work.

```
get %r{/hello/([\w]+)} do
    "Hello, #{params[:captures].first}!"
end
```

should correct map a route for `http://0.0.0.0:4567/hello` but is routing to a 'sinatra doesn't know this ditty' error message.

Thks.

Comment: Quick question are you restarting the web server after you copy and paste your code in.  Either that or use a gem like shutgun that reloads the web page after ever request

Comment: am usually restarting the webserver which is annoying, i'll load shutgun and see if it works, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%r{/hello/([\w]+)}` doesn't match `/hello` at all. Your regex requires a slash and another string, but your path doesn't include that.

That route would match `/hello/there` but not `/hello` or even `/hello/`.

And given that you are looking at the captures, you probably don't even want this to work with `/hello` at all since that capture would be `nil` and who want to say hello to `nil`?

Comment: thanks and interesting i was experimenting with rubular  couldn't i expect %r{/./} do  ... end  to route match anything on the root?  i couldn't make that work.  re the nil capture, yes that is correct but i'm less concerned with the code that runs and more concerned with the ability to regex match the route, ie, i want to matcha  few routes and then basically regex match all kinds of other stuff to a few get requests, this is purely educational on my part, thanks for the input.